# ubuntu 18.04 no sound

Tags: audio, driver, linux-device-driver, ubuntu-18.04

No sound on ubuntu 18.04 dell Inspiron 13. I'm not sure this pc require ALSA driver, maybe needs snd_soc_skl driver, Have someone try it? can you write how to change the kernel module in use in this Linux version?

Some details Inspiron-13-7368:~$ aplay -l 
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices **** card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3253 Analog [ALC3253 Analog] Subdevices: 0/1 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0 card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0] Subdevices: 1/1 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0 card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1] Subdevices: 1/1 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0 card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2] Subdevices: 1/1 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0 card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3] Subdevices: 1/1 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0 card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4] Subdevices: 1/1 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

Inspiron-13-7368:~$ lspci -v
 00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21) (prog-if 80) Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 152 Memory at d1128000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K] Memory at d1100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K] Capabilities: Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl

Comment: out of the box audio worked ?  before you changed something ?

Comment: work if I boot to windows.
In ubuntu it was working I not sure what happened that broke the sound

Comment: this forum is for coding questions ... ask your ubuntu questions over at sibling site https://askubuntu.com ... when I google :   .....   ubuntu 18.04 no sound   .....   first match points to    https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029502/no-audio-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://askubuntu.com

Comment: already look askubuntu answer(not helped), I believe in this forum maybe someone have a solution, by the way, code is just a way to do things, some extra information and help cannot affect anyone.

Answer (score 0):

What I found was to remove the "timidity-deamon":

```
sudo apt purge timidity-daemon
```

Thanks to Aaro Alhainen for [his post](https://aaroalhainen.medium.com/how-i-fixed-my-ubuntu-20-04-no-audio-dummy-output-issue-eaa525838e0d).

You can read about [timidity-deamon](https://packages.debian.org/unstable/timidity-daemon) package.